# Get first item in array where bool is false

Tags: c#, linq, unity-game-engine

I have GameObjects spawning in my game, those objects are being saved in an array.
That array gets sorted by distance from the player.

If the player has got his target (one of the objects) then that object his boolean "Claimed" needs to be set to true so other players cannot get that object anymore.

Instead they need to get the first item of that array where the boolean "Claimed" is false.

```
public void SearchFood()
{
    AllFood = GameObject
        .FindGameObjectsWithTag("Food")
        .OrderBy(x => Vector3.Distance(this.transform.position, x.transform.position))
        .ToArray();

    ClosestPieceOfFood = AllFood
        .First(Claimed => ClosestPieceOfFood.GetComponent<Food>().Claimed == false);

    ClosestPieceOfFood.GetComponent<Food>().Claimed = true;
}
```

The 2nd rule of the function is not working, im suspecting the problem being in "Claimed =>" but as im all new to Linq i don't really know where the problem is at.

I do not get any errors in my console log either about what could be the case.

Comment: `The 2nd rule of the function is not working,` you need to be more specific. Do you receive an error? Is the wrong item returned? Is it not compiling? This part looks suspect: `ClosestPieceOfFood.GetComponent<Food>().Claimed == false` shouldn't it be `food => food.Claimed == false`? or simply `f => !f.Claimed`

Comment: var firstnontrue = Allfood.where(f => f.Claimed == false).firstordefault()

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A lambda is just a short hand way to write a function.  In the case of `First` it takes a lamba that is passed in each item of the array and returns a `bool` and it will stop and return the first item that results in `true` from the lambda.  So I think you actually want something like.

```
ClosestPieceOfFood = AllFood.First(Food => Food.GetComponent<Food>().Claimed == false);
```

Or personally I'd prefer

```
ClosestPieceOfFood = AllFood.First(Food => !Food.GetComponent<Food>().Claimed);
```

You might also want to consider using `FirstOrDefault` in case there is no unclaimed food.  That will return `null` in that case where as `First` would throw an exception.  You'd then need to check if `ClosestPieceOfFood` is `null` and handle that case appropriately.

Also you can combine the code that creates the array and finds the first unclaimed food together and skip creating the array.

```
ClosestPieceOfFood = GameObject
    .FindGameObjectsWithTag("Food")
    .OrderBy(x => Vector3.Distance(this.transform.position, x.transform.position))
    .Select(x => x.GetComponent<Food>())
    .FirstOrDefault(Food => !Food.Claimed);

if(ClosestPieceOfFood != null)
    ClosestPieceOfFood.Claimed = true;
```

Comment: You basically threw away `ClosestPieceOfFood.GetComponent<Food>()` part of code...

Comment: @Fabjan Yes, because it doesn't make any sense in the lamba.  Now maybe it needs to be `Food => Food.GetComponent<Food>().Claimed == false`, but it's not really obvious if that's the case or not.

Comment: Adding the check if `ClosestPieceOfFood == null` made it work, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

```
public void SearchFood()
{
    var food = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Food")
           .OrderBy(x => Vector3.Distance(this.transform.position, x.transform.position)
           .First(x => x.GetComponent<Food>().Claimed == false);
    food.GetComponent<Food>.Claimed = true;
}
```

Your code looked a little weird and out of context so this could be wildly wrong.

But I think you just got a little confused with how lambdas worked.
also you can chain Linq methods so it's kind of handy to do that to not force multiple enumerations.